# How to store book/course reviews in typeorm (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I have an `Course`, `Task` and `Meeting` entities. I want to let user to give a review for particular `Course`, `Task` or `Meeting` and I'm wondering how to store them nicely in database. Of course I can do `CourseReview`, `TaskReview` and `MeetingReview` entities and link them via relations to their target entities but I was wondering whether shouldnt I create a single `Review` entity and somehow link each review to proper target entity. How to do it nicely? What columns should my `Review` entity have to be able to quickly get review of particular `Course` for example?

Comment: Unless a single review pertains to combination of  Course, Task, Meeting, just create the 3 tables. Assuming the answer is no then as to your question: How to do it nicely? *There is no way to do it nicely.* At a minimum your single `review` table would require a separate FK to each table and then you need to be sure exactly 2 of them are `null`. Do not get hung-up on the word Review. Your reviews pertain/reference totally different things. IMHO 3 specific tables is easier to work with and a cleaner model.